# Will it be possible to run android apps on ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

I know that the basic question of running android apps on ubuntu has already been answered, but mostly for ubuntu desktop. What I was wondering is, if there will be a way to download and run android apps on ubuntu phone. would be great because it would solve the problem of not having many apps available in the beginning...

Comment: It has been discussed in this link already. http://askubuntu.com/questions/247973/will-android-apps-be-compatible-with-the-ubuntu-phone-os

Comment: The contrary is certainly possible. https://askubuntu.com/q/1332793/124466

Answer (score 9):

In short the answer is:
**No**

The most important reason being that:
Ubuntu apps will be written in `QML toolkit` and `HTML5 technologies`. Whereas Android apps are mostly written in `Core Java`.

It has been discussed in detail at the following [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37165/26885)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no...You will probably not be able to run them natively.

But hey,this is the Linux world,someone will make a hack for you to be able to run them.