# How to use google text to speech with Foliate ebook reader installed in Ubuntu Base image in Android phone?

Tags: sound, android, arm, text-to-speech, foliate

I have [installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332793/how-to-install-ubuntu-apps-e-g-foliate-ebook-reader-on-my-android-device-runn) the Foliate ebook reader after installing Ubuntu Base image for Android phone.

I want to use [`gTTs`](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which uses Google speech to text service, as its voice is much better than `espeak` or `festival`. I have [enabled sound](https://docs.andronix.app/hardware/sound) in Termux.
The script in the [Foliate wiki](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/wiki#how-to-use-text-to-speech) uses `play` command from `sox`. However, for some reason, `sox` does not seem to work because it cannot find audio device (it seems that sox uses ALSA, but only Pulseaudio works with Termux in Android).

How do I use gTTs with Foliate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer **does not** require a rooted Android device.*
First [start Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332171/how-can-i-set-up-ubuntu-base-image-for-arm-on-my-android-phone-without-rooting) in Termux.

1. Install `gTTs` with pip.

   ```
   apt install python3-pip
   pip3 install gTTs
   ```
2. Install VLC (we would use VLC instead of `sox`).

   ```
   apt install vlc
   ```

   (mpv does not work because ffmpeg seems to have a [bug](https://github.com/Neo-Oli/termux-ubuntu/issues/82))
3. The Ubuntu base image logs in as the root user by default. However, `vlc` refuses to run as root. Let's allow VLC to run as root, following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199422/55205)

   ```
   sed -i 's/geteuid/getppid/' /usr/bin/vlc
   ```
4. Now, let us modify [the script](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/wiki#how-to-use-text-to-speech) in Foliate wiki to work with VLC.

   The original script was,

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gtts-cli -l $FOLIATE_TTS_LANG_LOWER --file /dev/stdin | play -t mp3 - &
   trap 'kill $!; exit 0' INT
   wait
   ```

   I found that `$FOLIATE_TTS_LANG_LOWER` often creates languages (e.g. `en-gb`) which are not present in gTTs catalogue. Since I primarily read ebooks in English, I replaced `$FOLIATE_TTS_LANG_LOWER` --> `en`.

   Also, by defualt, VLC does not quit after playing a media file. As a result, Foliate cannot automatically turn pages while reading out the text. We need to run the command line version of VLC (`cvlc`) with the `--play-and-exit` option.

   The modified script is,

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    gtts-cli -l en --file /dev/stdin | cvlc --play-and-exit - &
    trap 'kill $!; exit 0' INT
    wait
   ```

   Save this script in `/usr/local/bin/gtts`, and mark it as executable.

   ```
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gtts
   ```
5. Open Foliate preferences, and enter the command `/usr/local/bin/gtts` in the field for text-to-speech.